# Getting all child input elements within a div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get all the values of the input fields. The issue is all of the `<input type=radio/>` are dynamic and can increase or decrease at any time.

So I am starting with the main DI and going from there. The problem I have now is I am not getting the input radio buttons values.

So here are the steps I am intending to accomplish:

1. If any radio button is selected, pass its value to the checkbox value,
2. If the radio button is selected and the checkbox is not selected, do *not* pass to the checkbox value

I am looking for a solution in JavaScript only - **do not use jQuery**

Here is my [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/4aeag76o/4/)

#### HTML

```
<div style="display: block;" id="mymainDiv" class="fullFloat">

            <input type="hidden" value="1" id="startIdxShMdeCarWisevId" name="startIdxShMdeCarWise">
                <div class="subTitle">UPS<a class="fRight" onclick="localG('10',false,0,false,'UPS','1','$');" href="javascript:void(0);">Show Prices</a></div>
                <div style="display:none;" id="Wheel_UPS"><div class="loadingcheckout"></div></div>
                    <div id="Price_UPS">

                    </div>

                <div class="wrapLeft wrapClear">

                            <div class="wrapleft">
                                <label class="">
                                    <input type="radio" value="11098" id="deliveryMethodId_1" name="deliveryMethodId" class="section" data-mask="" data-rev="" data-rel="false" data-carrier=""> 



                                    <span>
                                        UPS Ground (Order by 9:30 PM EST)
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="wrapRight">
                                        <div id="UPS_11098">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        <input type="text" value="1" id="UPS">

                    </div>

            <input type="hidden" value="2" id="startIdxShMdeCarWisevId" name="startIdxShMdeCarWise">
                <div class="subTitle">Standard<a class="fRight" onclick="localG('20',false,0,false,'Standard','2','$');" href="javascript:void(0);">Show Prices</a></div>
                <div style="display:none;" id="Wheel_Standard"><div class="loadingcheckout"></div></div>
                    <div id="Price_Standard">

                    </div>
                <div class="wrapLeft wrapClear">

                            <div class="wrapleft">
                                <label class="">
                                    <input type="radio" value="11117" id="deliveryMethodId_2" name="deliveryMethodId" class="section" data-mask="" data-rev="" data-rel="false" data-carrier=""> 



                                    <span>
                                        Standard Delivery - 2-3 Day Delivery at Ground Rate (Order by 9:30 PM EST) 
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="wrapRight">
                                        <div id="Standard_11117">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        <input type="text" value="1" id="Standard">

                    </div>

            <input type="hidden" value="3" id="startIdxShMdeCarWisevId" name="startIdxShMdeCarWise">
                <div class="subTitle">FedEx<a class="fRight" onclick="localG('190',false,0,false,'FedEx','3','$');" href="javascript:void(0);">Show Prices</a></div>
                <div style="display:none;" id="Wheel_FedEx"><div class="loadingcheckout"></div></div>
                    <div id="Price_FedEx">

                    </div>
                <div class="wrapLeft wrapClear">

                            <div class="wrapleft">
                                <label class="">
                                    <input type="radio" value="11088" id="deliveryMethodId_3" name="deliveryMethodId" class="section" data-mask="" data-rev="" data-rel="false" data-carrier=""> 



                                    <span>
                                        FedEx Ground (Order by 8:00 PM EST)
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="wrapRight">
                                        <div id="FedEx_11088">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        <input type="text" value="1" id="FedEx">

                    </div>

        </div>
<input type="checkbox" name="shipmode" id="shipmode" value="" onclick="getpref('mymainDiv');">Get Value
```

#### JS Code

This executes when the checkbox is clicked:

```
function getpref(val) {
    var wr = document.getElementById(val);
    childElements = wr.childNodes;
    //alert(childElements);
    for(var i = childElements.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var elem = childElements[i];
        console.log(elem.id);
        if(elem.id && elem.id.indexOf(val+'_')==0){
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    //alert(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByName` to get you all of the radio buttons by `name='deliveryMethodId'` and then go from there:

```
function getpref(val) {
    var radioButtons = document.getElementById(val).getElementsByName("deliveryMethodId");

    for(var i = radioButtons.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        var radioButton = radioButtons[i];  

        if(radioButton.checked)
            console.log(radioButton.id + " is selected ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can directly access input nodes in your DIV with `getElementsByTagName`

```
function getpref(val) {
    var divNode = document.getElementById(val);
    var inputNodes = divNode.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputNodes.length; ++i){
        var inputNode = inputNodes[i];
        if(inputNode.type == 'radio') {
            //Do whatever you want
            if(inputNode.checked) {
                //Do whatever you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/88vp0jLw/1/